# How to get file name with blocks in UImagePickerController in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, block

I am capturing the image from camera and saving it to the phone gallery.

After saving the image I am getting the name of the last photo from the gallery.

I have written the code below, but it hangs the `picker` after i `tap` on use photo. Please tell me what is the issue with this.

```
    __block PHObjectPlaceholder *placeholder;
    PHPhotoLibrary *objPhoto = [PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary];
    [objPhoto performChanges:^{

    PHAssetChangeRequest *assets = [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromImage:info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]];
    PHObjectPlaceholder *placeholder = assets.placeholderForCreatedAsset;

    } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError * _Nullable error) {

      PHAsset *asset = nil;
      PHFetchOptions *fetchOptions = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
      fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:YES]];
      PHFetchResult *fetchResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeImage options:fetchOptions];
      if (fetchResult != nil && fetchResult.count > 0) {
        // get last photo from Photos
        asset = [fetchResult lastObject];
      }

      if (asset) {
        // get photo info from this asset
        PHImageRequestOptions * imageRequestOptions = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
        imageRequestOptions.synchronous = YES;
        [[PHImageManager defaultManager]
         requestImageDataForAsset:asset
         options:imageRequestOptions
         resultHandler:^(NSData *imageData, NSString *dataUTI,
                         UIImageOrientation orientation,
                         NSDictionary *info)
         {
           NSLog(@"info = %@", info);
           if ([info objectForKey:@"PHImageFileURLKey"]) {
             // path looks like this -
             // file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/###APPLE/IMG_####.JPG
             NSURL *path = [info objectForKey:@"PHImageFileURLKey"];
             refURL = path;
              NSString *strUrl  = refURL.absoluteString;
              NSArray *parts  = [strUrl componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
              orignalName = fileName = [parts lastObject];

              fileName = [[[Constant sharedInstance]getCommanFunctionInstance]generateFileNameWithExtension:filextension];
             [[AppSettings sharedAppSettings]setFileExtension:filextension];
             [[AppSettings sharedAppSettings]setFileName:fileName];
             [[AppSettings sharedAppSettings]setOrignalFileName:orignalName];

             [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
             [picker release];
             [self validateImage:2];

           }                                            
         }];
      }

    }];
```

Comment: is it crashing?

Comment: No but it is very slow.When i press "Use Photo" button then UIImagePickerController takes 5-6 seconds to dismiss

Comment: Try using background thread.

Comment: Make sure [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL]; is being executed in main thread. Add NSLog([[NSThread currentThread] description]); just before dismiss to check which thread is executing this line.

Comment: Can you please post some code here?